# how to call sys_open rather than sys_openat when calling open

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, system-calls

I write a code to generate system call

```c
void open_test(int fd, const char *filepath) {
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Open \"%s\" Failed!\n", filepath);
    } else {
        printf("Successfully Open \"%s\"!\n", filepath);
        write(fd, "successfully open!", sizeof("successfully open!") - 1);
        close(fd);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    const char fp1[] = "whatever.txt", fp2[] = "./not-exist.txt";
    int fd1 = open(fp1, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
    int fd2 = open(fp2, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
    open_test(fd1, fp1);
    open_test(fd2, fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

and another program(details omitted) to catch the system call, but later I found all `open()` turned out to call the sys_openat rather then sys_open.

The following text is the output of the program:

```
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fefef78aec8, Pathname is /etc/ld.so.cache
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fefef78aec8, Pathname is /etc/ld.so.cache
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fefef993dd0, Pathname is /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fefef993dd0, Pathname is /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fffd44e38e3, Pathname is whatever.txt
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fffd44e38e3, Pathname is whatever.txt
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fffd44e38f0, Pathname is ./not-exist.txt
Detect system call open, %rax is 257, Addr is 0x00007fffd44e38f0, Pathname is ./not-exist.txt
Successfully Open "whatever.txt"!
Open "./not-exist.txt" Failed!
```

here rax=257 means the sys_openat was called(for sys_open, rax=2)

Answer (score 6):

You call via the `syscall(2)` wrapper: `syscall(SYS_open, ...)`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(void){
        char *path = "whatever.txt";
        int fd = syscall(SYS_open, path, O_RDONLY, 0);
        if(fd == -1) err(1, "SYS_open %s", path);
}
```

But why bother? `SYS_openat` is the canonical system call now, `open(2)` is just an API, and the `SYS_open` system call entry is only kept for backward binary compatibility.

On newer architectures, there may be no actual `SYS_open` system call at all.

Comment: So you mean for latest Linux, sys_openat is used to replace sys_open?

Comment: Yes, and openat will maybe be replaced by openat2 at some point. The open(2) library API is implemented through openat on newer systems (and fork(2) through clone, etc). You should look at [uapi/asm/unistd.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h) for the list of the current "non-legacy" system calls, which a new arch should implement. As new interfaces are added and improved, the old ones are dropped from that list, while keeping the entry points on existing arch for compatibility with existing userland programs.