# Why does a call to open() is automatically replaced by openat() instead on linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, centos, system-calls

The following simple program is explicitly using `open()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd = open("/home/centos/AAA", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("open() returned ERROR\n");
        printf("errno: %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using `gcc` with no special flags:

```
gcc -Wall open_test.c -o open_test
```

However, using `strace` shows no calls to `open()`, but instead to `openat()`:

```
17893 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/centos/AAA", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

I understand it is many times preferred to use `openat()` over `open()`, but which part makes the implicit replacement and why? Is it the compiler? The OS?

**Platform**:
*CentOS 8 (kernel 4.18.0)*
*GCC 8.3.1*

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084547/how-to-call-sys-open-rather-than-sys-openat-when-calling-open

Comment: The simple answer is that `strace` traces syscalls (i.e. requests to the OS). `open()` and `openat()` are library functions which perform a syscall. Both do their work via the openat syscall.

Comment: Thanks to you both, that clarifies the issue